# Is it possible to use Tensorflow on GPU in Ubuntu without switching the PRIME profile to use the GPU?

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow, nvidia, ubuntu-16.04

I have a Lenovo Ideapad z50-70 with Intel integrated graphics and Nvidia 840M running Ubuntu 16.04. I am able to successfully run Tensorflow programs on the Nvidia GPU when I switch the PRIME profile in Nvidia driver to use the Nvidia graphics for display. Using the Nvidia card for display brings lot of issues such as system crashes when laptop is suspended and switching the PRIME profile requires logging out of the system. Is it possible to run the Tensorflow programs on the Nvidia GPU while using Intel's integrated graphics card for display, if yes how can I achieve this?

Comment: 16.04 drives me crazy. I have the same suspend problem. As a quick fix, you can press ctrl+alt+f1 then ctrl+alt+f7 and that usually fixes the problem after resuming.

Comment: This does not work for me. When I close the laptop lid with Nvidia GPU PRIME profile activated which suspends the system, the whole system completely crashes. I get stuck at black screen with either of two types of messages. The message displayed is either:
`NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:03:00): 79, GPU has fallen of the bus.`
or
`/dev/sda5: clean, 770062/10592256 files, 19943965/42339072 blocks`.
In this state the laptop does not seem to respond to anything.